# Issue involving sending mail with a WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I bought a theme on ThemeForest, it installed normally, but the contact form is having problems with the variables used.

Let me explain: the form has 3 fields (Name, Email and Message), the visitor fills out and submits, however, I get only the name and email address of the visitor, but I don't get the message that the visitor wrote.

I am in contact with the support of the theme for almost 10 days and they are not solving my problem.

I'm not a programmer, but I decided the little I know, I see clearly wrong in the formmail code (refer to fields / variables used).

See if you can help me solve:

- Send_mail.php : http://pastebin.com/MMjEnAy0
- Contact.php : http://pastebin.com/dd1Km2Hg

If you need any more information or file, I can post too.

Well, the file `send_mail.php` I'm finding a strange line 6 `( $ msg = " )`. Such is not the variable that should be written with any value or different?

I'm getting emails like this below:

```
    Name: Test João
    Email: teste-joao@email.com
    Subject:

    Message sent from website on date  Friday, March 14th, 2014, hour: 07:42 PM.


    Message:
```

I'm not a programmer. If you can help me.

Comment: Have you contacted themeforest about it as well? The problem with editing a theme directly is that if they make updates in the future it could overwrite your changes.

Comment: Hi Jrod! And yes, I made contact directly with the developer of the theme. But I do not know why it is not resolving. Besides the slow response. I spent all the data to access it, as requested, but is almost 10 days and the problem remains, with no response. Looks like it's a simple problem, because the name and email of the visitor is received, but the message he wrote not. Maybe it's something simple to fix. What I will do is qualify this developer (and theme) with 1 star on ThemeForest. But still need to resolve the problem, I can not be with the form without function :(

Comment: If you change `$_REQUEST[Message]` to `$_REQUEST[message]` in the send_mail.php file, it should let the message be printed.

Comment: Howlin, THANK YOU for your help. The problem was solved. Simple, and not even the developers were solving the issue. Again, thank you.

Comment: np, as for the subject, there is nothing in the form asking the user for a subject. Do you want that added?